# ODataController PUT not working

Tags: c#, odata

I have implemented an oDataController, everything works except the PUT verb. 
When I call it I get a 200 response regardless of what is in the request. 
When I put a break-point on the first line it is never hit. 
It seems like routing for that one verb isn't set up.
Even if I invalidate the Authorization header I still get a 200 OK response.
What should I do to diagnose the problem?
I am using Postman to test this (I tried fiddler to re-issue the PATCH as a PUT, and still get 200 OK)

Here's my WebApiConfig

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapODataServiceRoute(
            "oData routes for ...",
            "oData",
            GetEdmModel());
        config.EnsureInitialized();
    }

    private static Microsoft.OData.Edm.IEdmModel GetEdmModel()
    {
        var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder;
        var rpEntitySet = builder.EntitySet<RuralProfessional>("RuralProfessionals");
        var ceEntitySet = builder.EntitySet<CalendarEvent>("CalendarEvents");
        ceEntitySet.EntityType.HasKey(x => x.Key);
        var edmModel = builder.GetEdmModel();
        return edmModel;
    }
}
```

Here's the controller with the PUT method

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.OData;
using Terabyte.UmbracoWebsite.Infrastructure.CalendarEvents;
using Terabyte.UmbracoWebsite.ViewModels.ImportEvents;

namespace Terabyte.UmbracoWebsite.Controllers.oData
{
    /// <summary>
    /// To test this you will need to build auth header:
    /// https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/odatateam/2010/07/21/odata-and-authentication-part-6-custom-basic-authentication/
    /// </summary>
    [Authorize]
    [EnableQuery]
    public class CalendarEventsController : ODataController
    {
        readonly CalendarEventsRepository _repository = new CalendarEventsRepository();

        [AllowAnonymous]
        public IQueryable<CalendarEvent> Get()
        {
            return _repository.GetAll();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// example url: http://localhost:18903/odata/CalendarEvents(afbc13b6-84a5-4a3a-889c-1cf61f26c980)
        /// </summary>
        public SingleResult<CalendarEvent> Get([FromODataUri] Guid key)
        {
            var item = _repository.Find(key);
            return SingleResult.Create(new List<CalendarEvent>(){item}.AsQueryable());
        }

        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post(CalendarEvent item)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            var existing = _repository.Find(item.Key);
            if (existing == null)
            {
                _repository.Create(item);
                return Created(item);
            }
            else
            {
                _repository.Save(item);
                return Updated(item);
            }
        }

        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Patch([FromODataUri] Guid key, Delta<CalendarEvent> delta)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                return BadRequest(ModelState);

            var entity = _repository.Find(key);
            if (entity == null)
                return NotFound();

            delta.Patch(entity);
            _repository.Save(entity);
            return Updated(entity);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! BROKEN ... this doesn't get triggered.
        /// </summary>
        [System.Web.Http.HttpPut]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Put([FromODataUri] Guid key, CalendarEvent item)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid || key != item.Key)
                return BadRequest();
            _repository.Save(item);
            return Updated(item);
        }

        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Delete([FromODataUri] Guid key)
        {
            _repository.Delete(key);
            return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
        }
    }
}
```

The URL is: http://localhost:18903/odata/CalendarEvents(3da8432c-4c9f-40cc-9413-c82025720de8)
This works for PATCH verb, but not PIUT

Comment: If you receive response 200, then some action is certainly executed. Try setting breakpoints in each action of `CalendarEventsController`. If it does not help, please update your answer with full definition of `CalendarEventsController` and the url that you call from Postman.

Comment: Does adding the `[System.Web.Http.HttpPut]` attribute to the method do anything?

Comment: @CodeFuller yes I tried breakpoint in every action. I've updated the full code, NB the solution has a lot of other controllers, any hints on debugging the routing would be good?

Comment: @GWigWam I don't think the oDataController works like that, but I've added the attribute you suggested anyway, with no effect.